# How do I hide or remove the scrollbars that are appearing around my layout image while still keeping the image and text scalable?

Tags: html, css

[Site link](https://jessejamesthelawyer.com/)

I want the text and images on my site to be scalable with the browser window, which seems to be working, but something is causing scollbars to appear around the image I'm using for my layout. I think using GoDaddy as the host might somehow be causing this issue, but I don't know how to prevent the scollbars while keeping everything scalable and the text positioned.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script>
    var should_play=true
    window.onclick = () => {
        if (should_play){
            should_play=!should_play
            let soundSource = "https://bigsoundbank.com/UPLOAD/mp3/2216.mp3";
            let sound = new Audio(soundSource);
            sound.play();
            sound.onended = () => {
                should_play=true
            }
            }
            }
</script>
</html>
<body onclick="playAudio()" style="height: 1000px;"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alice|Ultra">
</head>
<body><div id="hero-container">
<img class="hero" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugdeybr9ibd2h3s/newspaper_main.png?raw=1" />
<div id="center-text">
<p id="paragraph">
Jesse James is a bright and talented attorney who lives by the mantra: “Honest, Careful, and Committed.” He is dedicated to his clients and always ready to do battle in the courtroom on their behalf. He has been described as a maverick, using creative strategies and techniques in every aspect of his practice. Jesse is committed to making sure his clients’ rights are protected and their positions are heard. He fights for truth, justice, and the American way – always striving to obtain the best possible outcome for each unique case.

Jesse grew up in West Virginia and obtained his undergraduate degree from West Virginia University. He worked as a Military Intelligence Analyst for six years, receiving both the Army Achievement and Army Commendation Medal. Following his honorable discharge, Jesse resettled in Arizona where he attended the Sandra Day O’Connor College of Law. He is now the owner of the private law firm, Jesse James ESQ., PLLC.
</p></div>
<p id="telephone">
PHONE: (304) 377-7322
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
#hero-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#center-text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 4%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
  
#paragraph {
  font-family: "Alice", serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  color:#2a2621;
  width:40%;
  text-indent: 4%;
  margin: 0;
} 

#telephone {
  z-index: 100;
  font-family: "Ultra", serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2.3vw;
  color:#2a2621;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.9%;
  left: 30.9%;
}

#hero-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
  img{
     display:block;
     margin: auto;  
}
</style>
</html>
```

I initially had the layout image set up as a background image, but I could not get the text to scale and stay in position alongside the layout image.

Comment: try set `body { overflow: hidden; }` ? Btw, it is a beautiful website :)

Comment: I find putting `text-align: justify;` to `#paragraph` fit well :)

Comment: I find a different between your posted code and the code in your site. Code posted `<body onclick="playAudio()" style="height: 1000px;">`, Code on site `<body onclick="playAudio()" style="margin: 0;">`, when I disabled the `margin:0` and your mentioned issue solved. Not sure you had updated your code or it is actually some code injected by others framework.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! Your suggestions worked perfectly. It might seem like an easy fix but I had been at this for hours already.

You're also absolutely right, I think the discrepancy you mention in your third response is likely code injected by the GoDaddy framework. I appreciate you pointing that out. Again, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
}

#hero-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

#center-text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 4%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
  
#paragraph {
  font-family: "Alice", serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color:#2a2621;
  width:40%;
  text-indent: 4%;
  margin: 0;
} 

#telephone {
  z-index: 100;
  font-family: "Ultra", serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color:#2a2621;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#hero-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
  img{
     display:block;
     margin: auto;  
}
```

```html
<head><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script>
    var should_play=true
    window.onclick = () => {
        if (should_play){
            should_play=!should_play
            let soundSource = "https://bigsoundbank.com/UPLOAD/mp3/2216.mp3";
            let sound = new Audio(soundSource);
            sound.play();
            sound.onended = () => {
                should_play=true
            }
            }
            }
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alice|Ultra">
</head>
<body><div id="hero-container">
<img class="hero" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ugdeybr9ibd2h3s/newspaper_main.png?raw=1" />
<div id="center-text">
<p id="paragraph">
Jesse James is a bright and talented attorney who lives by the mantra: “Honest, Careful, and Committed.” He is dedicated to his clients and always ready to do battle in the courtroom on their behalf. He has been described as a maverick, using creative strategies and techniques in every aspect of his practice. Jesse is committed to making sure his clients’ rights are protected and their positions are heard. He fights for truth, justice, and the American way – always striving to obtain the best possible outcome for each unique case.

Jesse grew up in West Virginia and obtained his undergraduate degree from West Virginia University. He worked as a Military Intelligence Analyst for six years, receiving both the Army Achievement and Army Commendation Medal. Following his honorable discharge, Jesse resettled in Arizona where he attended the Sandra Day O’Connor College of Law. He is now the owner of the private law firm, Jesse James ESQ., PLLC.
</p></div>
<p id="telephone">
PHONE: (304) 377-7322
</p>
</div>
</body>
```